# Is it appropriate to offer an alternate solution in ES6 for a pre-ES6 JavaScript question?

Tags: discussion

If a JavaScript question is asked and it is clearly written in pre-ES6, is it appropriate to offer an ES6 solution?

I personally have received a lot of value out of ES6 solutions that have been added to older questions. (Many of them being questions that were asked prior to the existence of ES6)

That being said, it's not what the person asked and it doesn't necessarily solve their problem if ES6 is not an option for them.

In some way it seems similar to PHP questions where someone posts an example using mysql_* functions and someone posts an answer with mysqli_* or PDO.

Example question:
[Traversing an Array Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978756/traversing-an-array-javascript/44978819#44978819)

Comment: If it's helpful, why not? just keep in mind that by doing so you will bump the post to the front page, for better or for worse. I wouldn't find a post that simply switches var to let/const and uses arrow functions where it makes no difference helpful.

Comment: The one you referenced for example, your answer doesn't really answer the question, which is the #1 thing all answers *must* do. you just said there's a logic error.

Comment: @rene Agreed. This is a dupe of that question. I voted to close this question as a dupe. Should I delete it instead? I've added more explanation and an ES5 solution. I guess we'll see if that's acceptable.